# Ant build pipeline failing in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, deployment, ant, yaml, salesforce

I am trying to run a pipeline in Azure Devops but the build is always getting failed with the following error **Property salesforce.password was circularly defined.**

This is the pipeline which I have created:

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- dev

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: Ant@1
  inputs:
    buildFile: 'build/build.xml'
    options: '-Dsalesforce.password=${salesforce.password} -Dsalesforce.username=${salesforce.username} -Dsalesforce.loginurl=${salesforce.loginurl} -Dsalesforce.testLevel=${salesforce.testLevel}'
    targets: 'deployCheckOnly'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion
```

All the values are added as a variable in Azure

This is the build.xml file:

```
<project name="Sample usage of Salesforce Ant tasks" default="deploy" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">

    <property file="build.properties"/>
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="ant.jar" value="ant-salesforce.jar"/>
    <property name="sf.username" value="${salesforce.username}"/>
    <property name="sf.password" value="${salesforce.password}"/>
    <property name="sf.serverurl" value="${salesforce.serverurl}"/>
    <property name="sf.testlevel" value="${salesforce.testlevel}"/> 

    <!-- Setting default value for username, password and session id properties to empty string 
         so unset values are treated as empty. Without this, ant expressions such as ${sf.username}
         will be treated literally.
    -->
    <condition property="sf.username" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.username"/> </not> </condition>
    <condition property="sf.password" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.password"/> </not> </condition>
    <condition property="sf.serverurl" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.serverurl"/> </not> </condition>
    <condition property="sf.testlevel" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.testlevel"/> </not> </condition>
    
    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
        </path>

    <taskdef resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:com.salesforce">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${ant.jar}" />           
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    
    <!-- Test out deploy and retrieve verbs for package 'mypkg' -->
    <target name="test">
      <!-- Upload the contents of the "mypkg" package -->
      <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="mypkg" rollbackOnError="true"/>
      <mkdir dir="retrieveOutput"/>
      <!-- Retrieve the contents into another directory -->
      <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="retrieveOutput" packageNames="MyPkg"/>
    </target>
    
    <!-- Shows deploying code and running tests only within the org namespace -->
    <target name="deployCodeRunLocalTests">
      <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="../force-app" rollbackOnError="true"  testlevel="RunLocalTests"/>
    </target>
</project>`
```

Comment: Just a note: properties in Ant are immutable, and references to unset properties are treated as string literals. So in the case where `salesforce.username` is unset, `sf.username` will be set to the literal value `${salesforce.username}` and the `condition` task that follows will have no effect. To do what I think you are trying to accomplish, you should have a single `condition` (no `property` task) that sets the `value` to `salesforce.username` if it is set, with `else` attribute setting it to "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to pass azure devops build variables you have to update this:

```
options: '-Dsalesforce.password=${salesforce.password} -Dsalesforce.username=${salesforce.username} -Dsalesforce.loginurl=${salesforce.loginurl} -Dsalesforce.testLevel=${salesforce.testLevel}'
```

to

```
options: '-Dsalesforce.password=$(salesforce.password) -Dsalesforce.username=$(salesforce.username) -Dsalesforce.loginurl=$(salesforce.loginurl) -Dsalesforce.testLevel=$(salesforce.testLevel)'
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax

Comment: Thanks @Shamrai it worked although I am getting a new error on running the pipeline
Must not connect to web server (e.g. login, www, test, or prerellogin) if providing a session id. 'serverurl' attribute should be a specific app server instance (e.g. na1, na2).

This is the url I have provided in the build variable sfdcdevelopment-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com

Comment: @code234 This is something related to salesforce, pls, check this answer: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000BdYOQA0. Additionally, you are trying using deployCheckOnly target, bit it is not defined in your build.xml sample.

Comment: I have updated he build.xml file. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @code234 pls accept here as an answer, maybe it will be useful for someone else.